# error deleting record from database in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to delete a record from database table but I get this error

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.TicketDetail_dbo.Person_PersonID". The conflict occurred in database "AbcDB", table "dbo.TicketDetail", column 'PersonID'

I'm sharing my code please guide me.

`TicketDetail`:

```
public class TicketDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int TicketDetailId { get; set; }
    public int? GenericOrderId { get; set; }
    public int? PartId { get; set; }
    public int? JunkPartId { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual Part Part { get; set; }
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual JunkPart JunkPart { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MailSystem> MailSystems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MailLog> MailLogs { get; set; }

}
```

`Person`:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }          
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

`Customer`:

```
public class Customer : Person
{
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TicketDetail> TicketDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MailSystem> MailSystems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MailLog> MailLogs { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Migration code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasMany<TicketDetail>(c => c.TicketDetails)
                .WithRequired(x => x.Customer)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

The error happens when I try to delete any `customerId`.

I have searched internet but couldn't find any appropriate solution, please help me with this error.

Comment: Does it work if you delete a customer by it's `customerId` in e.g. SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: @marc_s no it is not working in SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: OK, so you have a **fundamental** problem - you're trying to delete something that causes a foreign key reference to be violated. Read the error message closely - which tables are involved? How are they related? Are you trying to delete away a `Person` while there are still `TicketDetail` entries that reference that person? You cannot do that .... (that's the **whole point** of FK constraints!)

Comment: If you do want to delete the associated ticket details when deleting a person, you can always set a Cascade Delete Rule